# SYCL NDRange and Hierarchical: Why one of them is not enought?

Tags: parallel-processing, abstraction, hierarchical, sycl

SYCL offers NDRange and Hierarchical kernel parallelism abstractions.
My questions:

1. Is it true to claim that NDRange better mapped into GPUs hardware and Hierarchical parallelism better mapped into CPUs hardware?
2. Therefore, is it a realistic expectation that NDRange will achieved better performance on GPUs than Hierarchical parallelism, and on CPUs the opposite will occur?

Comment: Note: "Based on developer and implementation feedback, the hierarchical data parallel kernel feature described next is undergoing improvements [...]. As this is a key part of the SYCL API and we expect to make changes to it, we temporarily recommend that new codes refrain from using this feature until the new API is finished in a near-future version of the SYCL specification [...]." from [Hierarchical data parallel kernels](https://registry.khronos.org/SYCL/specs/sycl-2020/html/sycl-2020.html#_hierarchical_data_parallel_kernels)

Comment: Also: "This mode is purely a compiler feature and does not change the execution model of the kernel.", i.e. I would not expect the hierarchical parallelism stuff to do anything special, it just makes it easier to code and read the code.

Comment: Paleonix Thanks. I already know the comment you presented. But I received no answers to my questions. To remind you, the first draft of SYCL was presented in 2014. Therefore, when they say "in a near-future version" I don't know when it will happen.

Comment: paleonix, the second quote you provided and your comment contradict the first quote you provided. Because, if it only "makes it easier to code and read the code." Then, there is no need to improve Hierarchical parallelism in terms of performance and other aspects as they mentioned in your first quote.

Comment: They could just be changing the interface. If I was trying to answer the question, I would write an answer, not a comment. I don't have experience with the feature and am interested in an answer as well. Just trying to give some context (not necessarily to you, StackOverflow Q&As are aimed at future readers, not at the one who asked the question).